# Android ExoPlayer encounters buffering issues with certain streams

Tags: android, exoplayer

```
val factory = DefaultRenderersFactory(context)
    factory.setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER)
    val parameters = DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder()
        .setTunnelingEnabled(true)
        // todo : if some audio track is unavailable , change Audio Track after player initialized
        .build()

    val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(context, parameters)
    val loadControl = DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
        .setBufferDurationsMs(50000,
            50000,
            250,
            500)
        .build()


    val bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(context).build()
    val builder = ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
    player = builder.setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
        .setRenderersFactory(factory)
        .setLoadControl(loadControl)
        .setBandwidthMeter(bandwidthMeter)
        .build()
```

This is how I initialize ExoPlayer.
As you can see, I set DefaultLoadControl to Player and set other common options.

But I often get this warning message

```
W/DefaultLoadControl: Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
W/DefaultLoadControl: Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
W/DefaultLoadControl: Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
W/DefaultLoadControl: Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
W/DefaultLoadControl: Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
...
```

I just use Exoplayer to play a stream from a specific TV provider, but the server owned by that provider may be unstable, or the stream itself may be spurious.
Perhaps because of that, after the message that the Audiostamp does not match occurs repeatedly for a certain period of time, the message in the sample I posted above appears like crazy. And the reason why this phenomenon cannot be ignored is that OOM is waiting at the end of this phenomenon

Am I missing something? Desperately asking for help.